# Group elements to 1 variable to perform different functions on it

Tags: jquery, grouping, element

I have a list of different elements - often e.g. 30 controls , but for example:
`lbl1`,`lbl2`,`lbl3`

Now I'm sitting with a ton of duplicated code and it is difficult to maintain e.g.

```
$("#lbl1,#lbl2,#lbl3").show();
$("#lbl1,#lbl2,#lbl3").attribute('disabled','disabled');
$("#lbl1,#lbl2,#lbl3").hide();
```

etc
is there a way to say that

```
$("#lbl1,#lbl2,#lbl3") = x;
x.show();
x.attribute('disabled','disabled');
x.hide();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

it's [attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) not `attribute`  and better use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
var x = $("#lbl1,#lbl2,#lbl3"); //caching selector
x.show();
x.prop('disabled',true);
x.hide();
```

---

```
var x = $("#lbl1,#lbl2,#lbl3");
x.show().prop('disabled',true); //you can combine also
x.hide();
```

---

```
var x = $("#lbl1,#lbl2,#lbl3");
x.show().prop('disabled',true).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var x=$("#lbl1,#lbl2,#lbl3");
 x.show();
 x.attribute('disabled','disabled');
 x.hide();
```